# PHP Header information

Tags: php, curl, header, http-headers, httpresponse

I am a PHP developer. i am facing a problem on getting "Authorization variables" set by the user in request sent by using CURL.

I am not able to get these variables set by the user during curl request in my php code. Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to do it ? Please post what you have got so far in terms of code.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the values you are looking for are in the `$_SERVER` variables?

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php:

```
'PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'
When doing Digest HTTP authentication this variable is set to the 'Authorization' header sent by the client (which you should then use to make the appropriate validation). 

'PHP_AUTH_USER'
When doing HTTP authentication this variable is set to the username provided by the user. 

'PHP_AUTH_PW'
When doing HTTP authentication this variable is set to the password provided by the user. 

'AUTH_TYPE'
When doing HTTP authenticated this variable is set to the authentication type.
```

You should be able to access these variables like this:

```
$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
```

This will give you an idea of how to handle the different digests: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php